# Taylor expansion of a function of two variables, one of which is an exponent

Tags: real-analysis

Which is the Taylor series of the second order, centered at the origin, of the function:

$$
f(x,y)=(1+x^3)^y
$$

Comment: I think this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series maybe useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write your function as $ f(x,y) = \exp(y \log(1+x^3))$.
Now $\log(1+x^3) = O(x^3)$, so $$f(x,y) = \exp(O(x^3 y)) = 1 + O(x^3 y)$$
Thus the Taylor expansion to second order is just $1$.